# how to determine minimum number of lines for points location with respect to n sided regular polygon

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry

There is a n sided regular polygon and there is a point .What is the minimum number of lines a person has to draw to determine whether point is inside the polygon in worst case.For example for n=5 there should be 4 lines (worst case).How should i approach.

Comment: What information you gain after drawing some line exactly?

Comment: Point's location wrt line

Answer (score 0):

I am very confused by this question what exactly are you asking?

1. for point inside polygon test you need to cast just **1 line**

   - semi axis from that point to any direction and just count the intersections
   - the blue arrowed line on image below
   - see [hit test](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24465094/2521214)
2. did you mean how many lines this semi axis could hit instead?

   - in that case for **convex polygon 2 or 4** (4 if you hit the vertexes)
   - for N-lines **concave polygon N-1 or N** in the worst case.
   - the regularity does not mean anything in this case unless I misunderstood something ...
   - may be an image of what you want will be better then text
   - this is how I see it:

   [image: hit test edge cases]

   - blue dot is your tested point
   - blue arrow is casted semi axis
   - green lines are hit-ed lines of polygon